# Icons not showing up with Sencha Touch and Cordova for Windows 8

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, icons, sencha-touch

I have a fresh brand new install of Sencha Touch using Sencha CMD and I copied it to my web server, looks good.

I then bundled it in to a Cordova application within Visual Studio and the icons don't seem to be working. I see a letter "H" and an "R" instead of the "Home" and "Action" icons.

This is for a Windows 8 application.

Any one have any luck fixing this? I've seen some other threads with similar issues but they don't seem to work or don't give great instruction.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having the same problem under the same framework and target.  I expect your help about this... thank you.

Comment: No. I solved it by going with a different framework. The support from the Sencha guys was terrible and a dev shouldn't have to wait on issues like this and get virtually no answer on a commercial product (when asked on their forums). I liked the idea of separating the logic from the styling with a full JavaScript approach but in my project I ended up just going with jQuery Mobile and was happy to have a sucessful app launched and making money within weeks with great community support.